# Calculate mean and standard error of a generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

The goal of the following code is to calculate the mean and the standard error of vectors of randomly-generated numbers. I am looking for feedback both on the correctness of the calculation, and on its efficiency.

```
import numpy as np


def mean_and_stderr(num_of_iterations:int, instance_generator) -> (float,float):
    """
    Calculate the mean and standard error of the given generator.

    :param instance_generator: a function that accepts no parameters, 
             and returns either a float or a numpy array.
    :param num_of_iterations: number of times to run the instance_generator.

    :return a tuple: (mean, standard_error)

    Test on a degenerate (constant) generator of numbers:
    >>> generator = lambda: 5
    >>> mean_and_stderr(100, generator)
    (5.0, 0.0)

    Test on a degenerate (constant) generator of vectors:
    >>> generator = lambda: np.array([1,2,3])
    >>> mean_and_stderr(100, generator)
    (array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]))
    """
    sum = sumSquares = None
    for i in range(num_of_iterations):
        x_i = generator()
        if sum is None:
            sum = x_i
            sumSquares = (x_i*x_i)
        else:
            sum += x_i
            sumSquares += (x_i * x_i)
    mean = sum / num_of_iterations
    variance = sumSquares / num_of_iterations - (mean*mean)
    stderr = np.sqrt(variance) / num_of_iterations
    return (mean,stderr)



if __name__=="__main__":
    generate_uniformly_random_number = np.random.random
    print(mean_and_stderr(10, generate_uniformly_random_number))
    # Typical output: (0.5863703739913031, 0.026898107452102943)
    print(mean_and_stderr(1000, generate_uniformly_random_number))
    # Typical output: (0.514204422858358, 0.0002934476865378269)

    generate_uniformly_random_vector = lambda: np.random.random(3)
    print(mean_and_stderr(10, generate_uniformly_random_vector))
    # Typical output: (array([ 0.53731682,  0.6284966 ,  0.48811251]), array([ 0.02897111,  0.0262977 ,  0.03192519]))
    print(mean_and_stderr(1000, generate_uniformly_random_vector))
    # Typical output: (array([ 0.50520085,  0.49944188,  0.50034895]), array([ 0.00028528,  0.00028707,  0.00029089]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Formulas are flawed

Both these formulas are incorrect. They seem made up variants of the correct ones.

> ```
>  variance = sumSquares / num_of_iterations - (mean*mean)  
>  stderr = np.sqrt(variance) / num_of_iterations
> ```

Here are the correct formulas:

$$ \newcommand{smallm}[0]{\overset{n\ \gg\ m}{\longrightarrow}} \begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
                        \hline \\
               & \textrm{Formula} \\ 
                        \hline \\ \textrm{Variance} & \sigma² = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i - \mu)^2 \\ 
                        \hline \\ \textrm{Standard Deviation}  & \sigma = \sqrt{\sigma²} \\
                        \hline \\ \textrm{Standard Error}  & {\sigma}_\bar{x}\ = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \\
                        \hline \end{array}$$

#### Verification

Tool used to verify: [Online Standard Error Calculator](https://www.miniwebtool.com/standard-error-calculator/)

Note that the online test is compliant to a sample space, not an entire population. 
This means the formula used for variance is slightly different to take into account outliers:

$$s² = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2$$

Let's take a fixed input array to test your formulas.

```
 input array: { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 12 }
```

$$ \newcommand{smallm}[0]{\overset{n\ \gg\ m}{\longrightarrow}} \begin{array}{|l|c|c|}
                    \hline \\
           & \textrm{Mean} & \textrm{Standard Error} \\ 
                    \hline \\ \textrm{OP} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{red}{0.693888666488711} \\ 
                    \hline \\ \textrm{Corrected (sample space)} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{1.69967317119759} \\ 
                    \hline \\ \textrm{Corrected (population)} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{1.8618986725} \\ 
                    \hline \end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me from a severe bug. I did not use the standard formulas since they require  to do two passes on the data: one to calculate the mean $\mu$, and one to calculate the variance $\sigma^2$. Now, I found a way to do the correct calculation in a single pass:     
mean = sum / num_of_iterations;
population_variance = sumSquares / num_of_iterations - (mean * mean);
sample_variance = population_variance*num_of_iterations/(num_of_iterations-1);
stderr = np.sqrt(sample_variance / num_of_iterations);

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance: this MathJax library was not easy to use :) For future questions, I would suggest you add unit tests to your code. This way you can find bugs like this from the get-go.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Btw, read the answers on this question for a single pass calculation of both mean and variance: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185450/compute-mean-variance-and-standard-deviation-of-csv-number-file?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I'd want to address the `generator`, to begin. `:param generator: accepts no parameters and returns a vector` is false. The generator returns a number (with floating point or not). This is pretty confusing. When I read the code at first, I thought the generator would be an iterable that returns numbers (like `range(0,10)` for example).

In that case you wouldn't need to pass both the parameters `num_of_iterations` and `generators`. Otherwise, I don't think the parameter should be named `generator` or maybe your documentation should be stronger.

Next thing, you shouldn't initialize `sum = sumSquares = None` this way. They are numbers, initialize them at zero, that would give you the opportunity to remove your if/else.

```
sum = sumSquares = 0
for i in range(num_of_iterations):
    x_i = generator()
    sum += x_i
    sumSquares = (x_i*x_i)
```

Apart from that, the coding style is a little off. Sometimes you use `camelCase` and sometimes `snake_case`.

If we were to have an iterator instead of the generator, you could do something like this :

```
def mean_and_stderr(iterator) -> (float,float):
    sum = sumSquares = 0
    for x in iterator:
        sum = x
        sumSquares = (x*x)

    mean = sum / num_of_iterations
    variance = sumSquares / num_of_iterations - (mean*mean)
    stderr = np.sqrt(variance) / num_of_iterations
    return (mean,stderr)
```

Comment: I think `whatever_that_is_case` is called `snake_case` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Comment: It seems like the Python style guide itself refers to that style as [`lower_case_with_underscores`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). But it doesn't really matter :-D

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Probably my use of the word "generator" was confusing. I meant generator in this sense: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate i.e., a function without parameters. Like in the phrase "random number *generator*". Can you suggest a less ambiguous term?   
Also, the reason I initialize to None is that my "generator" can return not only a single number, but also a numpy array. See the second example in the doctest and the second example in the main program. Is there a more efficient way to handle both numbers and arrays in the same function?